# How to color entire rows on a tab?

Tags: tables, color

I'm a complete newbie to LateX, and I've been trying to make a multicolored tab. My issue is that (1) the text is not centered as I wished and (2) the color doesn't fill the entire row. Could someone telle me how to do it ? Thanks !

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, french]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{legalpaper, landscape, margin=0.5in}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[x11names,table]{xcolor}




\definecolor{Bleu}{RGB}{74,134,232}
\definecolor{Rouge}{RGB}{204,0,0}
\definecolor{Vert}{RGB}{147,196,125}
\definecolor{Jaune}{RGB}{255,153,0}



\begin{document}

 \begin{tabular*}{1\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}| c| c | c | c | c | c | c | }


\hline
 \textcolor{Rouge}{Question du colloque} & Auteur 1 Titre 1  & Auteur 2 &Auteur 3&Auteur 4&Auteur 5&Auteur 6 \\
\hline
\rowcolor{Bleu}
   Distinction conceptuelle& 1 - 2 & 1 - 3&1-4&1-5&1-6&1-7\\
\hline
\rowcolor{Bleu}

   Définition du concept clef& 1 - 2 & 1 - 3&1-4&1-5&1-6&1-7\\
\hline
\rowcolor{Bleu}

   Définition de la notion de {notion} & 1 - 2 & 1 - 3&1-4&1-5&1-6&1-7\\
\hline
\rowcolor{Rouge}
   Thèse Adverse & 1 - 2 & 1 - 3&1-4&1-5&1-6&1-7\\
\hline
\rowcolor{Rouge}

   Problème & 1 - 2 & 1 - 3&1-4&1-5&1-6&1-7\\
\hline
\rowcolor{Jaune}

   Thèse & 1 - 2 & 1 - 3&1-4&1-5&1-6&1-7\\
\hline
\rowcolor{Jaune}

   Référence & 1 - 2 & 1 - 3&1-4&1-5&1-6&1-7\\ 
\hline
\rowcolor{Jaune}

   Exemple & 1 - 2 & 1 - 3&1-4&1-5&1-6&1-7\\
\hline
\rowcolor{Vert}

  Arguments & 1 - 2 & 1 - 3&1-4&1-5&1-6&1-7\\
\hline
\rowcolor{Vert}

 Réponse à la question du colloque & 1 - 2 & 1 - 3&1-4&1-5&1-6&1-7\\
\hline

 \end{tabular*}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a try at `tabularx` package, where we can define a centered `X` column.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, french]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{legalpaper, landscape, margin=0.5in}
\usepackage[x11names,table]{xcolor}

\definecolor{Bleu}{RGB}{74,134,232}
\definecolor{Rouge}{RGB}{204,0,0}
\definecolor{Vert}{RGB}{147,196,125}
\definecolor{Jaune}{RGB}{255,153,0}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered X column

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|}
\hline
 \textcolor{Rouge}{Question du colloque} & Auteur 1 Titre 1  & Auteur 2 &Auteur 3&Auteur 4&Auteur 5&Auteur 6 \\
\hline
\rowcolor{Bleu}
   Distinction conceptuelle& 1 - 2 & 1 - 3&1-4&1-5&1-6&1-7\\
\hline
\rowcolor{Bleu}
   Définition du concept clef& 1 - 2 & 1 - 3&1-4&1-5&1-6&1-7\\
\hline
\rowcolor{Bleu}
   Définition de la notion de {notion} & 1 - 2 & 1 - 3&1-4&1-5&1-6&1-7\\
\hline
\rowcolor{Rouge}
   Thèse Adverse & 1 - 2 & 1 - 3&1-4&1-5&1-6&1-7\\
\hline
\rowcolor{Rouge}
   Problème & 1 - 2 & 1 - 3&1-4&1-5&1-6&1-7\\
\hline
\rowcolor{Jaune}
   Thèse & 1 - 2 & 1 - 3&1-4&1-5&1-6&1-7\\
\hline
\rowcolor{Jaune}
   Référence & 1 - 2 & 1 - 3&1-4&1-5&1-6&1-7\\ 
\hline
\rowcolor{Jaune}
   Exemple & 1 - 2 & 1 - 3&1-4&1-5&1-6&1-7\\
\hline
\rowcolor{Vert}
  Arguments & 1 - 2 & 1 - 3&1-4&1-5&1-6&1-7\\
\hline
\rowcolor{Vert}
 Réponse à la question du colloque & 1 - 2 & 1 - 3&1-4&1-5&1-6&1-7\\
\hline
 \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Oh my it's perfect, thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

- White space is caused by spaces between columns inserted by macro `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` which insert additional space between columns.
- You should be aware, that in landscape page orientation `\textwidth` and `\textheight` are interchanged.
- It is not clear, how the table width should be. I guess that you should instead of `\textwidth` use `\textheight` or simple `\linewidth`, however I maybe wrong.

With use of the `tabularray` package, the MWE (Minimal Working Example) may be:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[legalpaper, 
            landscape, 
            margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\definecolor{Bleu}{RGB}{74,134,232}
\definecolor{Rouge}{RGB}{204,0,0}
\definecolor{Vert}{RGB}{147,196,125}
\definecolor{Jaune}{RGB}{255,153,0}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\noindent%
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec    = {l *{6}{X[c]} },
             cell{1}{1} = {fg=Rouge},
             row{2-4}   = {Bleu},
             row{5-6}   = {Rouge},
             row{7-9}  = {Jaune},
             row{10-11} = {Vert},
                   }  
Question du colloque                & Auteur 1 Titre 1  & Auteur 2  & Auteur 3  & Auteur 4  & Auteur 5  & Auteur 6  \\
Distinction conceptuelle            & 1 - 2             & 1 - 3     & 1-4       & 1-5       & 1-6       & 1-7       \\
Définition du concept clef          & 1 - 2             & 1 - 3     & 1-4       & 1-5       & 1-6       & 1-7       \\
Définition de la notion de {notion} & 1 - 2             & 1 - 3     & 1-4       & 1-5       & 1-6       & 1-7       \\
Thèse Adverse                       & 1 - 2             & 1 - 3     & 1-4       & 1-5       & 1-6       & 1-7       \\
Problème                            & 1 - 2             & 1 - 3     & 1-4       & 1-5       & 1-6       & 1-7       \\
Thèse                               & 1 - 2             & 1 - 3     & 1-4       & 1-5       & 1-6       & 1-7       \\
Référence                           & 1 - 2             & 1 - 3     & 1-4       & 1-5       & 1-6       & 1-7       \\
Exemple                             & 1 - 2             & 1 - 3     & 1-4       & 1-5       & 1-6       & 1-7       \\
Arguments                           & 1 - 2             & 1 - 3     & 1-4       & 1-5       & 1-6       & 1-7       \\
Réponse à la question du colloque   & 1 - 2             & 1 - 3     & 1-4       & 1-5       & 1-6       & 1-7       \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Which gives to my opinion a bit nicer result:

[image]